# IntersectionObserver not registering on iOS, but works on Android, in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, intersection-observer

## What I have

I have made use of IntersectionObserver on my feed page. It behaves like TikTok. Scroll up or down to see the next video. On enter the video plays. On exit, it stops playing.

## The Problem

It works on Android and Windows perfectly. On iOS, not so much. The videos are not autoplaying as expected. A bit strange though, is if I click the video (which calls `play()` on that video), and then scroll it out of view, the video does stop. When I scroll it back into view, it auto plays again. So I know that IntersectionObserver is being recognized, just not triggered initially.

## The Code

==================================

The **Feed Page**, where the Observer is being instantiated:

```
data() {
    return {
      observer: null,
    }
  };
  mounted() {
    let config = { threshold: 0.1 };
    if (process.client) {
      if (/iPhone|iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        config.root = null;
      }
    }
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries) {
      entries.forEach(({ target, isIntersecting }) => {
        if (isIntersecting) {
          target.play();
        } else {
          target.pause();
          target.currentTime = 0;
        }
      });
    }, config);
 beforeDestroy() {
    this.observer.disconnect();
  },
```

***HTML***

```
      <div
        v-for="(post, index) in posts"
        :key="index"
      >
        <MobileFeedItem :post="post" :observer="observer" />
      </div>
```

=================================

The **MobileFeedItem** component

```
  props: ["post", "observer"],
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      if (this.observer !== null && this.checkMediaTypeIsVideo(this.post)) {
        this.observer.observe(
          document.getElementById(
            `video_${this.getContentId(this.post)}_mobile`
          )
        );
      }
    });
```

***HTML***

```
 <video
          :id="`video_${getContentId(post)}_mobile`"
          :data-poster="getThumbnail(post)"
          preload="none"
          disablePictureInPicture
          crossorigin
          loop
          playsinline
          v-lazy-load
          class="w-full h-full my-4"
        >
          <source :data-src="getMedia(post)" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
```

## My Thoughts...

The observer is being instantiated and recognized, just not triggered. So is there a way that I can force the browser to wake up and become aware of the observer without having to click on each of the video elements first?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It wasn't anything wrong with the IntersectionObserver, but because my video was not muted.

`"By default, autoplay executes only if the video doesn’t contain an audio track, or if the video element includes the muted attribute. Video playback pauses if the element gains an audio track, becomes unmuted without user interaction, or if the video is no longer onscreen"`

source - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/delivering_video_content_for_safari

It also appears that we don't need intersection observer at all for Safari, as it does this for us. Huh.